# Cycle detection DFS program exiting with key-error

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, depth-first-search

I am trying to implement cycle detection in a DAG and I am using a dictionary to keep track of the vertices that are in the recursion stack by setting their values to True in the dictionary. Once they exit, I set their value to one. In case I come across the same node, while it is in the recursion stack, its a cycle. 
The part of the code where I compare with recursion stack dictionary is getting skipped. I tried debugging the code but I don't seem to understand why it is not going into the comparison part in the recursive function.

PS: Guys, this not an assignment. I am just practicing.

The graph is:

```
directed_cyclic_graph = {
'g': ['h'],
'a': ['h', 'b'],
'b': ['c'],
'd': ['b', 'e'],
'c': ['f'],
'e': ['f'],
'i': ['i'],
'f': ['d'],
'h': [None]
}
```

The code :

```
def cycle_detection_recursive(adjList, vertex, parent, recursion_stack):
for nv in adjList[vertex]:
    # In the case there is a cycle to itself
    if recursion_stack[nv] and nv is not None:
        print("Loop detected", nv, "-->", nv)
    if nv not in parent:
        if nv is not None:
            parent[nv] = vertex
            if not recursion_stack[nv]:

                print(nv, "enters recursion stack")
                recursion_stack[nv] = True
            else:
                print("Cycle detected:", "back edge", nv, "-->", vertex)
            cycle_detection_recursive(adjList, nv, parent, recursion_stack)
            recursion_stack[nv] = False
            print(nv, "exits recursion stack")

def cycle_detection(DAG):
recursion_stack = {}
parent = {}
adjList = DAG

for vertex in adjList:
    if vertex not in parent:

        print(vertex, "enters recursion stack")
        recursion_stack[vertex] = True
        parent[vertex] = None
        cycle_detection_recursive(adjList, vertex, parent, recursion_stack)
        recursion_stack[vertex] = False
        print(vertex, "exits recursion stack")

def main():

    print("Breakpoint")
    cycle_detection(directed_cyclic_graph)
```

Finally, the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:/Coding_Practice/Dynamic_Programming/graph_traversal.py", line 194, in <module>
b enters recursion stack
main()
File "D:/Coding_Practice/Dynamic_Programming/graph_traversal.py", line 190, in main
cycle_detection(directed_cyclic_graph)
File "D:/Coding_Practice/Dynamic_Programming/graph_traversal.py", line 177, in cycle_detection
cycle_detection_recursive(adjList, vertex, parent, recursion_stack)
File "D:/Coding_Practice/Dynamic_Programming/graph_traversal.py", line 146, in cycle_detection_recursive
if recursion_stack[nv] and nv is not None:
KeyError: 'c'
```

Comment: instead of `if recursion_stack[nv]` use `if nv in recursion_stack and recursion_stack[nv]`

Comment: Why would that work?

Comment: You are getting key error. So, in `if nv in recursion_stack and recursion_stack[nv]` it will check for nv as key in recursion_stack first, if this condition fails it will exit the if clause.  If first condition pass, then it will check for the value i.e `recursion_stack[nv]`.

Comment: Oh yea got it. It was not checking if the key existed.